# SPARQL query with Turtle file (Public data source)

Tags: python, sparql, rdflib, turtle-rdf

I am new to Turtle format files and querying them with SPARQL. So I have many questions to be solved, I hope you can help me!

I have a file called equipamentsCURT3.ttl and contains the following:

```
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix v: <http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

<http://opendata.gencat.cat/recursos/equipaments/30883> a v:VCard ;
v:adr [ a v:Work ;
        v:country-name "Spain" ;
        v:locality "Sabadell" ;
        v:postal-code "08202" ;
        v:region "Vallès Occidental" ;
        v:street-address " c.  Sant Josep" ] ;
v:category "2. Parvulari"@ca,
    "3. Educació primària"@ca,
    "4. Educació secundària obligatòria"@ca,
    "Educació. Formació"@ca,
    "Ensenyaments de règim general"@ca ;
v:fn "Escolàpies Sabadell"@ca ;
v:geo [ v:latitude 4.154826e+01 ;
        v:longitude 2.111243e+00 ] ;
v:nickname "Escolàpies Sabadell"@ca ;
v:tel [ a v:Pref,
            v:Tel,
            v:Work ;
        rdf:value "937255348" ] .

<http://opendata.gencat.cat/recursos/equipaments/31264> a v:VCard ;
v:adr [ a v:Work ;
        v:country-name "Spain" ;
        v:locality "Molins de Rei" ;
        v:postal-code "08750" ;
        v:region "Baix Llobregat" ;
        v:street-address " c.  Ntra. Sra. de Lourdes" ] ;
v:category "4. Educació secundària obligatòria"@ca,
    "7. Batxillerat"@ca,
    "8. Cicles formatius d'FP de grau mitjà (CFPM)"@ca,
    "9. Cicles formatius d'FP de grau superior (CFPS)"@ca,
    "Educació. Formació"@ca,
    "Ensenyaments de règim general"@ca ;
v:fn "Institut Bernat el Ferrer"@ca ;
v:geo [ v:latitude 4.14105e+01 ;
        v:longitude 2.02704e+00 ] ;
v:nickname "Institut Bernat el Ferrer"@ca ;
v:tel [ a v:Pref,
            v:Tel,
            v:Work ;
        rdf:value "936683762" ] .

<http://opendata.gencat.cat/recursos/equipaments/31265> a v:VCard ;
v:adr [ a v:Work ;
        v:country-name "Spain" ;
        v:locality "Castellar del Vallès" ;
        v:postal-code "08211" ;
        v:region "Vallès Occidental" ;
        v:street-address " NC  Bonavista" ] ;
v:category "2. Parvulari"@ca,
    "3. Educació primària"@ca,
    "Educació. Formació"@ca,
    "Ensenyaments de règim general"@ca ;
v:fn "Escola Bonavista"@ca ;
v:geo [ v:latitude 4.161903e+01 ;
        v:longitude 2.091745e+00 ] ;
v:nickname "Escola Bonavista"@ca ;
v:tel [ a v:Pref,
            v:Tel,
            v:Work ;
        rdf:value "937144195" ] .
```

I am using Python3.5 and a library called RDFLib (https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib). I need to read from a file called equipamentsCURT.rdf, serialize it into equipamentsCURT3.ttl and then retrieve all information related to an equipment. For example, for the **equipment 30883** (http://opendata.gencat.cat/recursos/equipaments/30883), I want **v:adr,v:category,v:fn,v:geo and v:tel**. To obtain this data, I use SPARQL but I don't know why the query doesn't work. I'm very confused in how to query the information.

Here is my code:

```
import rdflib , pprint
from rdflib import URIRef, Graph
from rdflib.plugins import sparql

g = Graph()
g.load("equipamentsCURT3.ttl", format='turtle')

queryTest = 'prefix v: <http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#> ' \
'select ?y where {?x  a <http://opendata.gencat.cat/recursos/equipaments 30883>; ?y v:VCard .}'
qresult = g.query(queryTest)

for st in qresult:
 print rdflib.term.Literal(st).value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole query doesn't make any sense nor does it match the data.
I'd suggest reading a SPARQL tutorial first. The whole query looks like copy-paste from something else + some random stuff from your side.

1. the URI `http://opendata.gencat.cat/recursos/equipaments 30883` contains a white space which is wrong
2. `http://opendata.gencat.cat/recursos/equipaments/30883` is **not** a class. Thus, a triple pattern 
   `?x a <http://opendata.gencat.cat/recursos/equipaments/30883>`, which means to all resources that belong to the class `http://opendata.gencat.cat/recursos/equipaments/30883` doesn't match your data.
3. The second triple pattern is `?x ?y v:VCard`. And you're selecting the predicate `?y` as the final result of your query. But you want the objects for a given subject and a given set of predicates. Syntax of a triple /resp. triple pattern) is subject-predicate-object. Thus, for example for `v:category` it should be

```sql
PREFIX v: <http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#> 
SELECT ?o WHERE {
  <http://opendata.gencat.cat/recursos/equipaments/30883>  v:category ?o 
}
```

For the other properties it will be more complicated since the values itself are blank nodes that have attached multiple values via additional properties. E.g. for `v:adr` it would be

```sql
PREFIX v: <http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#> 
SELECT ?p ?o WHERE {
  <http://opendata.gencat.cat/recursos/equipaments/30883>  v:adr ?adr .
  ?adr ?p ?o 
}
```

### Update

If you don't want the values but the properties it's correct to have the variable in predicate position. But it's wrong to restrict it to those properties that occur only in triples with the object `v:VCard` because there is no such property besides `rdf:type` (`a` is just a synonym for it). In that case it should be

```sql
PREFIX v: <http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#> 
SELECT DISTINCT ?p WHERE {
  <http://opendata.gencat.cat/recursos/equipaments/30883>  ?p ?o 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @AKSW. One last thing, and I'll mark your answer as valid to my problem. In the first query you posted, the format I get is (rdflib.term.Literal(u'2. Parvulari', lang=u'ca'),), that's ok, but if I want only '2. Parvulari', what should I do?

Comment: Calling `.value` on the Literal object should return the *lexical form*, which is basically what you want.

Comment: .value doesn't work. I have:  for st in qresult: print rdflib.term.Literal(st).value

Comment: Can you please update your code example in the question such that we can see the whole code that your're running to parse the query result?

Comment: Done! But I'm not parsing the query result... :(

Comment: With parsing I meant processing - in your case you're iterating over the resultset. `print st['o'].toPython()` or `print st.o.toPython()` should work

Comment: Sorry AKSW, what should I do if I want to retrieve to v:tel from different URIs? I mean, in the file are 3 equipments, what should I do to retrieve the v:tel from these equipments. At this moment, I know with one URI, but for 3... I'm thinking of creating an array of URIs and then perform the query, but I don't know how to combine the array with the query. THNKS!

Comment: You can either select all instances of type `v:VCard` in the dataset or if you have a given set of URIs, you can use SPARQL 1.1 VALUES clause: `PREFIX v: <http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#> 
SELECT ?s ?o WHERE {
  VALUES ?s  {<URI1> <URI2>} ?s v:tel ?o 
}`

Comment: Is there a more "automatic" way of doing it? I mean, for 3 is easy, but for 2000 URIs, will be insane..

Comment: As I said, if all belong to the same class like in your sample data `v:VCard` you can select all instances of this class with SPARQL. `PREFIX v: <http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#> SELECT ?s ?o WHERE { ?s a v:VCard . ?s v:tel ?o }`